# Chrome keyboard shortcuts, external Bluetooth keyboard, Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-tab, chrome-for-android, external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

There are a lot of Google hits in which people report that the usual desktop Chrome keyboard shortcuts (e.g., ctrl+t for a new tab) work fine on Android Chrome with an external Bluetooth keyboard.

However, none of the shortcuts seem to work in my system. I am using the following setup:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1
- Android 4.0
- Chrome web browser
- Microsoft Wedge Mobile Keyboard
- Nothing strange configured or installed; I have recently reset the tablet

For example, these things work OK:

- System-wide shortcuts (e.g. win+l for Calendar) work.
- If I tap on the address bar in Chrome, I can use the keyboard to enter a URL.
- I can also edit the address as usual when the address bar is active. Arrow keys work, ctrl+a works, ctrl+c / ctrl+v works, etc.

However, these things seem to do nothing:

- Using any of the usual keyboard combinations in Chrome: ctrl+t, ctrl+n, ctrl+l, ctrl+w, etc.

Comment: This guy claims working keyboard shortcuts on Note 10.1 http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/16pcqx/til_that_chrome_for_android_supports_the_same/

Comment: I tried to plug-in a USB keyboard via OTG. Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Cltrl+V works, but not Ctrl+T (and the others). I don't have a bluetooth keyboard. So, I can't try.

Answer (score 1):

Installing **[External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper)** seemed to fix the keyboard shortcuts in Chrome.

(I have no idea why it helps; this was completely unexpected. I was just installing it to get rid of the onscreen keyboard.)